# Declare value from CSV for SQLCMD query

Tags: sql-server, csv, vbscript

I have written a SQL query to search for specific loyalty sales in a date range as below, yes this is a VBScript question…

```
DECLARE @datefrom date = '01-Jul-2015'
DECLARE @dateto date = '23-Aug-2015'
SELECT CONVERT(nvarchar,[SaleDate],112) as SaleDate, year(saledate) as SaleYear, month(saledate) as salemonth, day(saledate) as saleday,
COUNT([CustID]) as Customers, SUM([SaleTotal]) as SaleTotal
FROM [Server].[dbo].[LoyaltyTransactions]
WHERE LoyaltyTranTypeID =11 and SaleDate between @datefrom and @dateto
GROUP BY convert(nvarchar,[SaleDate],112), year(saledate), month(saledate), day(saledate)
ORDER BY convert(nvarchar,[SaleDate],112)
```

The issue is I don’t want to  be modifying the date from/to every time the end user wants a different date range, so I decided to try and write my first VBScript.

Ive managed to write the following so that from a HTA GUI out puts the end users Start & End date (DD-MMM-YYYY) input to a CSV file.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>LRR</title>
</head>
<HTA:APPLICATION
 CONTEXTMENU="no" 
 SCROLL="no"
 SINGLEINSTANCE="yes"
 Navigable="yes"
 BORDER="dialog"
/>
    <script language="VBScript">
    Sub SaveData
        Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        If objFSO.FileExists("F:\DISKSETS\SCRIPTS\SQLREPORT\Report.txt") Then
            objFSO.DeleteFile("F:\DISKSETS\SCRIPTS\SQLREPORT\Report.txt")
            Set objFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile("F:\DISKSETS\SCRIPTS\SQLREPORT\Report.txt")
            strLine = SD.Value & "," & ED.Value & ","   
            objFile.WriteLine strLine
            objFile.Close
        End If
    End Sub
    Sub Window_onLoad
        window.resizeTo 320,230
    End Sub
            Sub RunProgram
        Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
        objShell.Run "F:\DISKSETS\SCRIPTS\SQLREPORT\Report.vbs"
    End Sub
</script>
<body>
<p><span style="font-size:16px;">&nbsp;</span><u><strong><span style="font-size:16px;">Loyalty Redemption Report</span></strong></u></p>
<p><strong><span style="font-size:14px;">&nbsp;START DATE : <input maxlength="14" name="SD" size="14" type="text" value="DD-MMM-YYYY" />&nbsp;</span></strong></p>
<p><strong><span style="font-size:14px;">&nbsp; &nbsp;END DATE :&nbsp;<input maxlength="14" name="ED" size="14" type="text" value="DD-MMM-YYYY" /></span></strong></p>
<p>&nbsp;<strong><span style="font-size:14px;"><input name="REPORT" type="button" value="REPORT" onclick="SaveData" /></span></strong></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is where I get stuck I now need the VBScript to pull the two dates from the CSV and put them in SQL Query ive written above.

From there ill be able to use SQLCMD to get the query in VBSCript to output to excel.

TIA.

Answer (score 0):

You already have retrieved SD.Value and ED.Value (presumably these are the dates) so why not just pass them to the vbscript call as parameters?

```
<html>
<head>
<title>LRR</title>
</head>
<HTA:APPLICATION
 CONTEXTMENU="no" 
 SCROLL="no"
 SINGLEINSTANCE="yes"
 Navigable="yes"
 BORDER="dialog"
/>
    <script language="VBScript">
    Sub SaveData
        RunProgram SD.Value, ED.Value
    End Sub
    Sub Window_onLoad
        window.resizeTo 320,230
    End Sub
    Function RunProgram(startDate, endDate)
        Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
        objShell.Run "F:\DISKSETS\SCRIPTS\SQLREPORT\Report.vbs " & startDate & " " & endDate
    End Function
</script>
<body>
<p><span style="font-size:16px;">&nbsp;</span><u><strong><span style="font-size:16px;">Loyalty Redemption Report</span></strong></u></p>
<p><strong><span style="font-size:14px;">&nbsp;START DATE : <input maxlength="14" name="SD" size="14" type="text" value="DD-MMM-YYYY" />&nbsp;</span></strong></p>
<p><strong><span style="font-size:14px;">&nbsp; &nbsp;END DATE :&nbsp;<input maxlength="14" name="ED" size="14" type="text" value="DD-MMM-YYYY" /></span></strong></p>
<p>&nbsp;<strong><span style="font-size:14px;"><input name="REPORT" type="button" value="REPORT" onclick="SaveData" /></span></strong></p>
</body>
</html>
```

In your vbscript, these parameters will be accessible using `WScript.Arguments(0)` and `WScript.Arguments(1)`, indicating the first and second parameters being passed in.